# Understanding advanced ZeroMQ socket types

Tags: zeromq

I've read the 0MQ guide, and I understand the basic socket types: `PUSH`/`PULL`, `REQ`/`REP`, and `PUB`/`SUB`.

I'm very confused though about `ROUTER`/`DEALER` and the `X`- sockets (e.g., `XSUB`/`XPUB`, `XREQ`/`XREP`).

What are the use cases for these socket types?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Trivial Archetypes

ZeroMQ "***sockets***" are sounding alike a socket-oriented device, however on a closer look this smart library rather adds a Formal Communication Pattern ( which btw. uses a true *socket* ) that has a layered design to internally address details like internal elastic-buffering, internal 1:N Fair-Queue-Sending / Polling, internal ioThread load-balancing, to name just a few.

Atop on these internal smart subsystems, aka the elementary Formal Communication Patterns -- named as close as possible to resemble a human-alike behaviour -like- (one)-`PUB`-lishes + (others)-`SUB`-scribe -- ZeroMQ **builds** a "ground floor" of much more powerful messaging schemes.

As a good helper, instead of saying a `PUB`-*socket*, one may opt to imagine a `SUB`, `XPUB` or `DEALER` to be rather an **entity-with-"*behaviour*"**, **sitting on one end of the phone-line**, who has some hard-wired ***habits***, that it can use during a phone-call.

So, some entities can speak one to the other, alike `PUB` can speak to one or many `SUB`(s) - without knowing how many / if any is (are) connected to his, well, to **any** of his phone-lines ( yes, `PUB` can have many outgoing phone-lines -- plus for details check the ZeroMQ transport Classes available, that `PUB` can "expose for incoming calls" or otherwise deploy --( Oh yes, even `PUB` can "pick up one of his phone-lines" and dial ( .connect() towards ) a selected `SUB` or `XSUB` counterparty! Cool... (Yes, as many ZeroMQ features designed-in) )-- all of that in parallel.

`SUB` can upon its discretion decide and subscribe to filter, what to hear and what not to hear from the incoming phone-line. Naturally, some others are simply not equipped within their pre-wired behaviour to be able to universally phone each other and get meaningfully get into a viable conversation, but can talk to it's "friendly" (behavioral-compatible) counterparty ( a `PAIR`, as an example, has a one and the only chance to go and ring + speak to another `PAIR`-buddy ).

For deeper understanding of these building blocks, incl, the `XPUB`/`XSUB` motivation, why they had to extend the plain `PUB`/`SUB` primitive, the best way one can recommend is to read [Pieter Hintjens' **book "Code Connected, Volume 1"** ( downloadable as pdf)](http://hintjens.wdfiles.com/local--files/main%3Afiles/cc1pe.pdf).

( IMHO a must-read book, not just about the smart properties of ZeroMQ per-se, but about the shift in mindset and other inspiring thoughts ).

### `ROUTER`/`DEALER` & `DEALER`/`ROUTER`

These Formal Communication Patterns are well illustrated in Fig.37 and discussed around, in the said book. Worth reading it, than just getting a few words here.

A `ROUTER` to `DEALER` example ( a **1-to-N** use case ) where one server talks asynchronously to multiple workers can be turned "upside down" to get a very useful **N-to-1** architecture where various clients talk to a single server, and do this asynchronously. So exact use-case is given by your design need.

### `XPUB` / `XSUB` use case

Once getting to the "**inter-mediated**" mode of connections among the ZeroMQ primitive elements, the `XPUB`/`XSUB` proxy "device" serves one more add-on service than just being a proxy to `.bind()` & `.connect()` to. It also "interpretes" the message-content ( checking incoming `zmq.SUBSCRIBE`-s & transfers 'em towards the real-`PUB`-lisher side via the proxy own `XSUB` ) by reading the `XPUB` socket side.This is the main use case for `XSUB` and `XPUB`

Mastering the ZMQ arsenal element-by-element as such is not the goal per-se. It is rather a LEGO-style kit of building blocks for designing project-specific distributed messaging patterns, that co-operate according to a more complex need -- self-healing after a single node failure, performance-scaleability, adaptive-reconfiguration and many others.

Just one picture, Fig.60:

[image]

### Complex Systems

Typical real-world application has to go much farther than just to re-use the elementary `PAIR`/`PAIR`, `XREQ`/`XREP`, ... primitives, where these appropriately fit into your higher-level design needs, and atop of which you add a behaviour strategy, that uses these lower-level archetypes under your global design control.

For getting code arranged, worth spending a time with the book first, not vice versa.

This will save you a lot of Aha! moments later.