# 0MQ telnet data C++

Tags: c++, networking, zeromq, telnet

I'm trying to get working sending **`telnet`** commands with 0MQ with C++ on VS2013.

I used HW client sample code from ZMQ hompage.

But what I see on WireShark is **telnet packet** with no data inside.

This code is prototype, what I need is just to be able to send this command.

After making it work, it will get some cleaning.

```
//
//  Hello World client in C++
//  Connects REQ socket to tcp://localhost:5555
//  Sends "Hello" to server, expects "World" back
//
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <zmq.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    //  Prepare our context and socket
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t socket(context, ZMQ_REQ);

    std::cout << "Connecting to hello world server…" << std::endl;
    socket.connect("tcp://10.40.6.226:23");

    //  Do 10 requests, waiting each time for a response
    for (int request_nbr = 0; request_nbr != 1; request_nbr++) {
        zmq::message_t request(2);
        memcpy(request.data(), "Hello", 5);
        std::cout << "Sending Hello " << request_nbr << "…" << std::endl;
        socket.send(request);
        //client_socket

        //  Get the reply.
        /*zmq::message_t reply;
        socket.recv(&reply);
        std::cout << "Received World " << request_nbr << std::endl;*/
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So everything looks good beside I'm cannot see the string "Hello" in telnet packet.

Original sample http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:hwclient

Comment: Are you... trying to connect a ZMQ socket to a telnet server directly?  This will not work - ZMQ sockets need to connect to other ZMQ sockets under normal circumstances.  If you *need* to make it happen, then there are certain RAW modes that will allow you to connect and send to non-ZMQ endpoints, but you'd better know what you're doing.  The TCP packet you're seeing is probably related to establishing the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, one can send `telnet` commands over ZeroMQ

There is no principal obstacle in doing this. Once you correctly setup the end-to-end relation over ZeroMQ, your `telnet`-commands may smoothly flow across the link, meeting all the required underlying protocol-specific handshaking and event-handling.

### Why it does not work here?

The strongest reason "behind" the observed scenario is, that you have **missed the essence** of the ZeroMQ **Formal Communication Patterns** framework.

ZeroMQ sockets are not "plain"-sockets as might the re-use of the word socket remind. There would be close to none benefit if ZeroMQ would just mimick a dumb-socket already available from the operating system. The greatest intellectual value one may benefit from ZeroMQ is based right on the opposite approach. Thanks to a several thousands man*years of experience that were put into the birth of AQMP and ZeroMQ & their younger ancestors, there are smart features built-in the framework which we are happy to re-use in our application domains, rather than trying to re-invent the wheel again.

### The best next step?

Supposing one's interest in smart messaging is not lost, the best next step IMHO is to spend one's time on reading a [great **book "Code Connected, Vol.1"** from Pieter HINTJENS, a co-father of the ZeroMQ >>> https://stackoverflow.com/a/25742744/3666197](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25742744/3666197)

---

### + a minor note, why the code does not move any data over a wire

A good design practice brought into the ZeroMQ architecture, have separated a transport per-se from the connection-state of a socket-archetype. That said, one may "pump-data-into" a local end of a-socket-archetype ( your code **`.send()`**-s 10x in a for loop ) but a remote-end need not be online throughout that whole episode ( or at all ). This means, the PHY-layer ( the wire ) will see and transport any data if-and-only-if both endo-points of the Formal Communication Pattern agree to do so.

In the **`REQ/REP`** scenario that means

1. `{REQ|REP}`**`.bind()`** `<-online-visibility-episode->` `{REP|REQ}`**`.connect()`** state
2. `REQ`**`.send()`**`->   REP`**`.recv()`**
3. `REP`**`.send()`**`-> ( REQ`**`.recv()`**`)`
4. `REQ`**`.send()`**`->`

keeping the nature of the Merry-Go-Round policy of the **`REQ/REP`** Formal Communication Pattern "forward-stepping".

In the posted `for(){...}` code-block this means that if **`step 1.`** is met you may wire-detect just the first and the only one message from **`REQ`** to **`REP`**, as you seem not to take care to perform mandatory steps `2.` & `3.` to  **`.recv()`** a response from **`REP`** before the `REQ`-behavioural model will allow to send any next request ( which is the core nature of the `REQ/REP` pattern, isn't it? ).

Once your ZeroMQ insight gets farther, you would also get used to check errors associated with respective function calls.

Invoking a `.connect()` attempt, directed ( fortunately over **`port 23`** ) to the hands of a `telnet-daemon` will be visible on a wire-level, however a protocol-level handshaking would hardly allow a correctly formulated ZeroMQ-wire-level protocol message ( which will for sure surprise the wire-level sniffer if in non-transparent mode ( assuming a telnet ) ) to make happy the telnet-daemon process, which is waiting for nothing else but a telnet-protocol-session setup dialogue, which in described scenario simply must fail to get met.