# ZeroMQ REQ/REP: must REP send something back?

Tags: zeromq

I'm using the pattern **`REQ`**/**`REP`** of [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org).

Normally this pattern works like this:

```
REP.bind(localhost with a port)
REQ.connect(localhost with the same port)

REQ sends a REQ-message to REP

REP sends a REP-message to REQ back
```

Now, I want to remove the last step.
Meaning that `REP` doesn't send back anything, it just receives the messages from `REQ`.
I know there another pattern named **`PUB`**/**`SUB`** to do this but I just want to use **`REQ`**/**`REP`**.

Here is my code:

```
// REQ
int main()
{
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new();
    void *requester = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_REQ);
    zmq_connect(requester, "tcp://localhost:5555");
    const char * msgSent = "I'm agent";
    zmq_send(requester, msgSent, strlen(msgSent), 0);
    zmq_close(requester);
    zmq_ctx_destroy(context);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

// REP
int main()
{
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new();
    void *responder = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_REP);
    zmq_bind(responder, "tcp://*:5555");
    while (true) {
        char buffer[50] = {'\0'};
        cout << "receiving..." << endl;
        zmq_recv(responder, buffer, 50, 0);
        cout << buffer << endl << "end";
    }    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I first run `REP`, it will show "receiving..." on the console, meaning that it is waiting for some message.
The I run `REQ`, which sends a message to `REQ`.

After that, the console of `REP` will show "I'm agent" BUT then the `while` will keep going. It seems that `zmq_recv` is NON-BLOCKING.

I thought it would stop after receiving "I'm agent" but it didn't. But If I make REP to send something back to `REQ`, everything will be fine.

**WHY?**

MUST `REP` send something back?

Comment: Yes, when sockets are REQ-REP then REP must send something back. From what you described, it seems that a pipeline pattern is what you'd benefit from (PUSH - PULL sockets). They are unidirectional, when a PUSH sends a message then PULL just has to read it. You can use combination of two PUSH-PULL pairs to implement async REQ-REP. You can also use the [ROUTER-DEALER](http://zguide.zeromq.org/php:chapter3#The-DEALER-to-ROUTER-Combination) combination which is what I described (async req-rep).

Comment: @Mjh   thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem, have fun with ZeroMQ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ZeroMQ is a very smart and very powerful LEGO-style toolbox

Still, it cannot provide things the very way you ask it. If there was some reason to develop a highly scaleable formal communication pattern, that mimicks `REQ`-asks/`REP`-replies, then there is this principal reason behind ZeroMQ architecture, why your attempts to get other than this expected behaviour simply have to fail.

### Yes, `REQ`-asks and principally waits, till `REP`-reply is `REQ`-read-in

For formally non-prescribed peer-to-peer behaviour, one may implement `PAIR`/`PAIR` Formal Communication Pattern and enjoy the full freedom.

### The best next step?

What I can do for your further questions is to direct you to see a [bigger picture on this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25742744/3666197) with more arguments, a simple signalling-plane / messaging-plane illustration and a direct link to a must-read book from Pieter HINTJENS.