# ZeroMQ to send messages between systems

Tags: zeromq

I am very much new to the `ZeroMQ` library.

Hence I wanted to know the pattern ( `REQ-REP`, `PUSH-PULL`, `PUB-SUB` ) that will be the best for our application.

The application which we are using has two systems,
the one which the **user interacts with**
and
the second is the **scheduler**, which executes a job, scheduled by the user in the first system.

Now I want to make use of `ZeroMQ` to send messages in the below scenarios:

1. from **`userSystem`** to **`schedulerSystem`** that a job with particular job `id` is submitted for execution.
2. from `schedulerSystem` to `userSystem` that the job sent with a particular job `id` has been executed succesfully or the execution has failed

Can somebody please help with this,
stating the reason for using a particular pattern?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read the guide? This topic is covered there. Long story short, the efficient types would be `PUSH` and `PULL` combinations. Since those two are usually difficult for people, there exists a combination of two socket types `ROUTER` and `DEALER` which "look" like `REQ` and `REP` but are asynchronous under the hood. It means it's easy to implement and it's efficient. [Follow this link](http://zguide.zeromq.org/php:chapter3) and look for **figure 38**.

Comment: @Mjh: Thank you so much. We started out trying with the ROUTER- DELAER model, but later on requirment of persisting the the messages was added . So now we are exploring the  "Disconnected Reliability (Titanic Pattern) given in the [link](http://zguide.zeromq.org/php:chapter4)

Comment: I'm glad you have it working, have fun using ZMQ :)

Answer (score 0):

### Which is the best Formal Communication Pattern to use? None...

Dear Ann,
with all due respect, nobody would try to seriously answer a question which of all the possible phone numbers is the best for any kind of use.

**Why?** There is simply no Swiss-Army-Knife for doing just anything.

**That is surprisingly the good news.**
As a system designer one may create <kbd>**The Right Solution**</kbd> on a green-field, using the just-enough design strategies for not doing more than necessary ( overhead-wise ) and have all the pluses on your design side ( scaleability-wise, low-latency-wise, memory-footprint-wise, etc. )

### If no other requirements than (1) and (2) above appear,
<sub>a light-weight scheme
like this may work fine as an MVP "just-enough" design:</sub>

If **`userSystem`** does not process anything depending on a **`schedulerSystem`** output value, a **`PUSH-PULL`** might be an option for sending a job, with possible extensions.

For **`userSystem`** receiving independent, asynchronously organised state-reporting messages about respective `jobID` return **`code`**(s), again a receiver side poll-ed **`PUSH-PULL`** might work well.

**Why?** Otherwise natural unstructured behaviour-wise **`PAIR-PAIR`** disallows your processing from growing in scale once performance or architecture or both demand to move. `PAIR-PAIR` does not allow your communication framework to join more entities together, while others do and your processing power may go distributed until your IP-visibility and end-to-end latency permit.

### The real world is typically much more complex

Just one picture, Fig.60 from the below-mentioned book:
[image]

---

### The best next step?

[To see a **bigger picture on this subject >>>**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25742744/3666197) with **more arguments**, a simple **signalling-plane picture** and a **direct link to a must-read book from Pieter HINTJENS**.