# ZeroMQ blocking one-to-many pattern

Tags: design-patterns, zeromq, blocking

I have read through the `ZeroMQ` documentation and think I understand the 3 basic patterns: **`REQ/REP`**, **`PUB/SUB`**, **`PUSH/PULL`**.

However, I don't see how they allow me to construct something where A sends messages to both B and C, with blocking behavior.

That is, let's say I set a limit to 1024 messages for both A->B and A->C. Then, if a queue fills up, I would like A to stop sending messages, until there is room in both receivers, instead of just dropping the messages (`PUB/SUB`).

`PUSH/PULL` does not deliver each message to both A and B, but only one of them.

**Is there a way to do this with `ZeroMQ`?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### A: Yes, there is

**`ZeroMQ`** is a wonderfull toolbox. After many years I would dare to say, any of it's pre-built **S**caleable **F**ormal **C**ommunication **P**attern to be a basic pattern. Each one is rather an example of a formal behaviour and sure, [there are many cases, when these trivial behavioural pattern do not **fit the needs the software Projects would like to have** and advanced scenarios are coming to the stage.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25742744/3666197)

There we go.

Consider `ZeroMQ` to be rather an enabler toolbox, not a solution provider. So, let's put sleeves up and start designing the very mix of behaviours, that are needed for the Project.

Messaging and signalling components benefit from built-in features of `ZeroMQ` elements. The design shall make the missing parts and the glue logic to match the Project specification.

Once `ZeroMQ` socket-end-point does not give you any code-driven control on it's blocking behaviour, you need to add such one.

Let's imagine the A to have an incoming socket **`A_IN`** ( being `PULL` on `A`-side ). This way your code can control when and for how long it will ( will not ) `PULL` next incoming message, based on your Project-specific logic, implementing the mutually bonded buffering/blocking policies, based on states from monitoring both buffering-watermarks and messaging-socket-state of exgress-traffic directed sockets `A_OUT_2_B` and `A_OUT_2_C` ).

This way your code can add controls for explicit, Project-specific, management of the blocking state of `A_IN`, add element-state inspection features, it's reflectivity to other external control / system signals and many other features one may wish to have in place.

> **Welcome** to the worlds of **`ZeroMQ`** & **`nanomsg`** and enjoy it's powers for both messaging and smart signalling in the distributed systems

[If interested in more answers on elementary & advanced ZeroMQ topics, **feel free to read other `ZeroMQ`** & **`nanomsg`** related posts.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bzeromq%5D%20is%3Aanswer)