# How to stop a thread that is waiting for Client to .connect()?

Tags: python, thread-safety, zeromq, pyzmq, xbmc

Basically I have this problem:

I use ZMQ to use a **`PUB/SUB`** formal pattern to publish some pieces of data to other programs. First class, i.e. a Server waits for a client to `.connect()` and when the client connects, Server sends the data to the Client.

I use `ZMQ REQ/REP` to synchronize Server and Client.

This is **`Server.py`**:

```
class PublishThread (threading.Thread):
def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    socketPub.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:4002")
    syncservice.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5001')
def run(self):
    while True:
        subscribers = 0
        topic = b"PHONEBOOK"
        while subscribers < 1:
            # Here we wait for client to connect. If the client doesn't 
            #connect, this is where this thread will "hang"
            syncservice.recv()
            # Send response to client
            syncservice.send(b'')
            subscribers += 1

        socketPub.send_multipart([topic, data1])
        subscribers = 0
```

**Q1:** How can I stop this thread when I want to exit my program?
 Because when I want to exit my program, program "hangs" because thread is still running and waiting for a client.
**Q2:** How do you think that it will be best to implement this?
**Q3:** Is there any other way than **`REQ/REP`**?

Comment: Add a timeout to the code that hangs

Comment: This code is far from a **StackOverflow promoted MCVE method** of posting the high quality Questions. Text states (cit.:) "... Server ... Client ... REQ/REP" but no such elements are in code. **Update your Question to contain a fully representative MCVE for both the server & client** that can reproduce the problem you are asking the Community to help diagnose and fix. **This is the StackOverflow preferred way** to constructively solve and discuss any kind of MCVE related issues. Anyway, **welcome to this great Community of knowledge** and feel free to contribute in our way forwards.

Answer (score 2):

ZeroMQ is a very powerful set of tools for smart distributed applications with messaging and signalling features ready to be "just used" ( if one knows how - anyway, [do not hesitate to follow the book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25729055/understanding-advanced-zeromq-socket-types/25742744#25742744) ).

---

**A1:** First, you need to start design your code-units in a non-blocking, asynchronous mode, so that you can still keep control over your threaded code independently of any internal/external blockers. As a lesson No.1, one has to forget to use just the naked **`.recv()`** and mentally switch into **`zmq.NOBLOCK`** and/or loop-controlled **`.poll( nMSECs )`** where necessary ( not all ZeroMQ wrappers have such a comfort the `pyzmq` has, so do benefit from this bonus ).

---

**A2:** as a rule-of-thumb, one may use several additional **`SIG`** and **`DIAG`** messaging `ZeroMQ`-patterns added to the core-logic of any threaded code-unit. This helps you both in testing and in ad-hoc changes in any kind of internal settings ( effectively adding a distributed **`CLI`** interface to your code-unit is cool by-product thereof, isn't it? ) and/or termination of the thread.

---

**`A3:`** Oh sure there is. Whenever one feels a `REQ/REP` Formal Communication Pattern is the right one, check the book again and re-design the code so that it can survive `REQ/REP` inability to get itself from de-synced distributed-**`FSA`**-stepping once it has silently fallen into de-synced state. Many posts refer to this principal issue.

---

Epilogue: sharing ZeroMQ-socket instances in threads is strongly discouraged.

Comment: Hi again. Thanks for correcting my error - that was not deliberate. I have re-corrected the spelling again (powerful, graceful, etc. all have one L, not two). Your edit message is again inappropriate, and I would much rather you saw my edits in a positive light, and allow me some leeway to make honest mistakes. My edits are, again, not attacks on your work. All the best.

Comment: **Thank you**. This was actually my error. Just 've used a copy/paste. Brain was switched off :o) **Hope you use some ML/NLP lexer**, not to have to read all my historical sins & grammar errors in person :o) Enjoy the weekend, Sir.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to stop your thread is to send a shutdown message, create a `shutdown` property, initialized with a boolean false value, then set it as a condition to run your server (in a `while` loop, set **`while !shutdown:`**) then once your server receives a shutdown request from the client you will modify the value of the shutdown property with true which will stop the while loop and then shutdown your thread.

Comment: I have tried that, but the problem is, that Thread hangs and waits for the Client. So if client doesn't connect, Thread will just hang and wait for syncservice.revc(). So if i close the program, Server will still just wait, because it won't loop through while True all the time..

Comment: As has been posted in the Answer above, the toys work in a bit more complex way. The ZeroMQ calls `.recv()`  and `.send()` above, in the MCVE code, are fortunately **blocking**. Besides the fact, this is not a good design practice in most production-grade software design, this also prevents any thread-level soft-signalling or hard SIG_KILL  signalling to succeed. The more due to the fact, that the actual blocking is hidden in a state-of-execution in another threat ( the .Context() instance, belonging to the .Socket() instance ( not necessarily the central one ...) ). Plus the REQ/REP deadlock.