# How to protect ZeroMQ Request Reply pattern against potential drops of messages?

Tags: c#, python, network-programming, zeromq, connectivity

I'm trying to implement a **ZeroMQ** pattern on the TCP layer between a **c#** application and distributed **python** servers.  I've gotten a version working with the request-reply **`REQ/REP`** pattern and it seems relatively stable when testing on **`localhost`**. However, in testing, I've debugged a few situations, where I accidently send multiple requests before receiving a reply which apparently is not acceptable.

*In practice the network will likely have lots of dropped packets and I suspect that I'll be dropping lots of replies and/or unable to send requests.*

**1) Is there a way to reset the connection between `REQ/REP`** request-reply **sockets?**
Would a `REOUTER/DEALER` pattern instead make more sense? As this is my first application with ZeroMQ, I was hoping to keep it simple.

**2) Is there a good ZeroMQ mechanism for handling the connectivity events?**  I've been reading "the guide" and there are a few mentions of monitoring connections, but no examples.  I found the **`ZMonitor`**, but can't get the events to trigger in c#.

Comment: Why not use a poller on the REQ side and wait for the response for a limited time. If there is none you should close/destroy the socket, create a new one and try again.

Comment: The guide said that creating and destroying sockets multiple times was bad practice. Apparently there's no guarantee that the underlying socket will close until the context is terminated... Which shouldn't happen until I'm disposing the owner.

Comment: That depends on how often sockets are closed and reopened. The guide suggests closing and reopening sockets in the "Client-Side Reliability (Lazy Pirate Pattern)" section (http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Client-Side-Reliability-Lazy-Pirate-Pattern)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Ad 1) No**,
 there is not any socket link-management interface exposed to user to test/reset the state of the FSA-to-FSA link in ZeroMQ framework.

Yes, **`XREQ/XREP`** may help you overcome the deadlocks, that may & do happen in `REQ/REP` Scaleable Formal Communication Pattern:

> Ref.: **`REQ/REP`** Deadlocks >>> https://stackoverflow.com/a/38163015/3666197

**`Fig.1:`** Why it is wrong to use a naive **`REQ/REP`**
all cases when `[1]`**`in_WaitToRecvSTATE_W2R`** + `[2]`**`in_WaitToRecvSTATE_W2R`**
are principally unsalvageable mutual deadlock of `REQ-FSA/REP-FSA` Finite-State-Automata and will never reach the "next" **`in_WaitToSendSTATE_W2S`** internal state.

```
               XTRN_RISK_OF_FSA_DEADLOCKED ~ {  NETWORK_LoS
                                         :   || NETWORK_LoM
                                         :   || SIG_KILL( App2 )
                                         :   || ...
                                         :      }
                                         :
[App1]      ![ZeroMQ]                    :    [ZeroMQ]              ![App2] 
code-control! code-control               :    [code-control         ! code-control
+===========!=======================+    :    +=====================!===========+
|           ! ZMQ                   |    :    |              ZMQ    !           |
|           ! REQ-FSA               |    :    |              REP-FSA!           |
|           !+------+BUF> .connect()|    v    |.bind()  +BUF>------+!           |
|           !|W2S   |___|>tcp:>---------[*]-----(tcp:)--|___|W2R   |!           |
|     .send()>-o--->|___|           |         |         |___|-o---->.recv()     |
| ___/      !| ^  | |___|           |         |         |___| ^  | |!      \___ |
| REQ       !| |  v |___|           |         |         |___| |  v |!       REP |
| \___.recv()<----o-|___|           |         |         |___|<---o-<.send()___/ |
|           !|   W2R|___|           |         |         |___|   W2S|!           |
|           !+------<BUF+           |         |         <BUF+------+!           |
|           !                       |         |                     !           |
|           ! ZMQ                   |         |   ZMQ               !           |
|           ! REQ-FSA               |         |   REP-FSA           !           |
~~~~~~~~~~~~~ DEADLOCKED in W2R ~~~~~~~~ * ~~~~~~ DEADLOCKED in W2R ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|           ! /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\|         |/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/!           |
|           ! \/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/|         |\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\!           |
+===========!=======================+         +=====================!===========+
```

---

**`Fig.2:`** One may implement a free-stepping transmission layer using several pure `ZeroMQ` builtins and add some SIG-layer tools for getting a full control of all possible distributed system states.

**`App1.PULL.recv( ZMQ.NOBLOCK )`** and **`App1.PULL.poll( 0 )`** are obvious

```
[App1]      ![ZeroMQ]
code-control! code-control           
+===========!=======================+
|           !                       |
|           !+----------+           |         
|     .poll()|   W2R ___|.bind()    |         
| ____.recv()<----o-|___|-(tcp:)--------O     
| PULL      !|      |___|           |   :   
|           !|      |___|           |   :   
|           !|      |___|           |   :   
|           !+------<BUF+           |   :     
|           !                       |   :                           ![App2]
|           !                       |   :     [ZeroMQ]              ! code-control
|           !                       |   :     [code-control         ! once gets started ...
|           !                       |   :     +=====================!===========+
|           !                       |   :     |                     !           |
|           !                       |   :     |         +----------+!           |
|           !                       |   :     |         |___       |!           |
|           !                       |   :     |         |___| <--o-<.send()____ |
|           !                       |   :<<-------<tcp:<|___|   W2S|!      PUSH |
|           !                       |   :    .connect() <BUF+------+!           |
|           !                       |   :     |                     !           |
|           !                       |   :     |                     !           |
+===========!=======================+   :     +=====================!===========+
```

**Ad 2) No**,
 but one may create one's own **"ZeroMQ-consumables"** to test the distributed system's ability to setup a new transport/signalling socket, **being ready to dispose it, if the RTO-test fails to prove that both ( multiple ) sides are ready to setup + communicate over the ZeroMQ infrastructure** ( notice, that the problems are not only with the ZeroMQ layer, but also the App-side need not be ready/in such a state to handle the expected communication interactions ( and may cause soft-locks / dead-locks ).

---

### The best next step?

[What I can do for your further questions right now is to direct you to see a **bigger picture on this subject >>>**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25742744/3666197) with **more arguments**, a simple **signalling-plane / messaging-plane illustration** and a **direct link to a must-read book** from Pieter HINTJENS.

Comment: Oh my. Didn't know about deadlocks. I have some more reading to do. Thanks for the push.

Comment: Why did they ban you, again? Checked the chats, found nothing, curious :)