# ZMQ python programming

Tags: deep-learning, raspberry-pi, zeromq, detection, pyzmq

I have got an object detection which reads an input image and runs the inference then it outputs the `classIDs[]` (class name) and confidence levels of the detected object `confidences[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could you please tell me how can I communicate the output ... from deep learning system?

May use a `socket.send( pickle.dumps( [ classIDs[i], confidences[i], ] ) )`

Both the first O/P-topic creeping comment, posted 15 minutes after this answer did answer the O/P-problem definition (and was deleted later) and also the second O/P-topic creeping comment, posted about an hour after a due answer was in-place, did not change the game :

whatever you try to pass over the ZeroMQ channel has to be SER/DES-handled. If willing to make things complex, ok, it still goes the same way :

```
socket.send( pickle.dumps( <whateverBLOBneeded> ) )
```

If starting to have new problems, due to SER/DES-collisions ( as object-instances and Class()-es have so often in attempts to have them `pickle`'d ), feel free to try to salvage the so often Exceptions "vomiting" `pickle` module with : **`import dill as pickle`** a smarter SER/DES `dill` module from Mike McKerns and, again the rest goes the same way :

```
socket.send( pickle.dumps( <whateverBLOBneeded> ) )
```

### A bonus part

May rather want to **prototype** with `PUSH/PULL` it does not block in a [mutual deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40429335) as all `REQ/REP` do.

Comment: The function : objectClassInference(filename): is introduced for object detection task. Actually I was thinking of introducing a function through this program.   So that it can run and provides class name and confidence level as output.  I already wrote the object detection part. I thought that would be too much code if I posted it. The detection code is very long. I wanted to define this function properly so that it grabs the output of the detection code and send it to the client.

Comment: can you please look at this post as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60309791/how-do-you-define-function-for-communicating-object-detection-output