# Is there any ZeroMqChannel channel timeout?

Tags: java, spring, zeromq, distributed-computing

I have a `ZeroMqChannel` object that I use to retrieve data. Every week service going offline, due to a maintenance, and `ZeroMqChannel` instance keeps connection and doesn't even throw any exceptions.

Is there any way to throw a timeout error and try to reconnect later?

```
    @Bean(name = "zeroMqChannel")
    public ZeroMqChannel zeroMqPubSubChannel(ZContext context) {

        ZeroMqChannel channel = new ZeroMqChannel(context, true);
        channel.setConnectUrl(url);
        return channel;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having my hands dirty with ZeroMQ-API since v2.1 ( 200?... - the time is flying so fast ),
I dare claim,
the problem is in the re-wrapping (with adding design compromises) of an already re-wrapped (with cruel(*) design omissions) ZeroMQ [native API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25729055/understanding-advanced-zeromq-socket-types/25742744#25742744).

JeroMQ documentation *( as of 2022-Q1 based on `libzmq 4.1.7` )* says :

> *TCP KeepAlive Count, Idle, Interval cannot be set via Java but as OS level.*

---

WORKAROUND ?

In native-API designs, we may easily try to programmatically `.bind()` / `.connect()` another temporal-"link" between persistent (one indeed, the other becoming switched off each week), and already deemed by a code-designer to be still inter-linked ZeroMQ [AccessPoints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46620571), so as to try if the remote service AccessPoint is actually still indeed alive or if it had gone down, for the said maintenance ( without sending a proper signal to its [distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing) counterpart. So rude & unfair practice among cooperating agents', isn't it? Fair & smart systems indeed cooperate, even on planned re-configuration, before disconnecting from peer(s) - this is why ZeroMQ messaging + signalling meta-plane designs are so cute to make distributed-computing robust & smart in production, isn't it? I dare to imagine, how many distributed-FSA [un-salvageable deadlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40423825/how-to-protect-zeromq-request-reply-pattern-against-potential-drops-of-messages/40429335#40429335) happen for such rude-mode in `REQ/REP` cases ).

Details matter & depend on the re-wrapping of the re-wrapped native ZeroMQ API. There we can have one `PUB/SUB`-link operating as many "co-parallel"-links, setup & torn-down on-the-fly (using a failure of an attempt to setup a new one as a self-diagnosing tool for detecting remote AccessNode unable to get connected to and make serve this side-effect to our advantage).

All this depends on the actual design of the wrappers. The native API provides even socket-monitor, that could solve part of these issues in a clear & sound manner, yet not sure, if that got implemented in JeroMQ & Spring-integration wrappers.

Documented re-wrapping of the ZeroMQ Zen-of-Zero into highly abstracted, yet internally super-inconsistent, "adaptor" details confuse me a warn me to be very careful of what else we loose from the smart original if using it :

> The `ZeroMqChannel` is a `SubscribableChannel` which uses a pair of ZeroMQ sockets to connect publishers and subscribers for messaging interaction. It can work in a `PUB/SUB` mode (defaults to `PUSH/PULL`); it can also be used as a local inter-thread channel (uses `PAIR` sockets)

*)

- no ipc:// transport-class (emulated over tcp://loopback-port)
- no pgm:// transport-class
- no norm:// transport-class
- no tipc:// transport-class
- ...
- PUB/SUB filtering, based on TOPIC, may be, yet need not be so, re-configured by the sender into a multi-frame message ( i.e. without a knowledge or a participation on control thereof by any of the, potential many, SUB-side(s) )
- "chameleon"-alike typing of the (re-wrapped) smart ZeroMQ Scalable Formal Communication Pattern archetypes, now original `PUB/SUB` becoming suddenly `PUSH/PULL`, with all changed "behavioural"-patterns. This is hard for me to consider a positive for doing system designs ( creeping properties IMHO serve no benefits - new users get lost as never see the native-API original smartness and powers, experienced users get panic as all the smart features of the native-API do not work as-is, but got re-dressed into mixture of originally super-clean, performance optimised concepts, hybrid `{ PUSH/PULL | PUB/SUB }`-mutable-mezzo-types are error prone in re-use in otherwise classical & stable use-case patterns, causing further concept misses & hidden design-compromises are just a few losses caused by such hybrid & liquid landscape )
- and many more

Comment: Is it good idea to create service with timer which will make ```ZeroMqChannel``` instance reconnect on timeout? And reset timeout time on receiving message

Comment: IMHO any kind of a non-blockin, distributed behaivour protocol is better, than a "blind-belief". Most of my systems were sub-us low-latency & performance focused, where overhead costs were killing. In your, week-long service (having some planned maintenance window) has plenty of time to do also a few things besides the core-transport. Having 1 transport-channel + 1 bidirectional signalling channel ( to heartbeat, to announce & bilaterally agree on (when) going into service dismantling & service-reinstation -- a preferred design. Adding some N+1/N+M robust "central" dispatcher even a better one