# ZeroMQ PGM Multicast doesn't support reply handling from application layer?

Tags: c++, zeromq, jzmq, pgm-protocol

I have done a sample ZeroMQ PGM multicast application and it is working fine.

But reply handling is not working. **Is this correct approach or not?**
If yes - how to do any reply from a Receiver to the Sender?

**Sender:**

```
std::string msg = "hello";
socket->send(msg.c_str(),msg.length(),0);
socket->recv(reply);                          // Can we do this?
```

**Receiver:**

```
char msg[100] = {0};
std::string reply = "Succ";
socket->recv(msg,100,0);
socket->send(reply.c_str(),reply.length(),0); // Can we do this?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, no!

Yes, the ZeroMQ **`pgm://`** transport-class does not support this.

No, we cannot do this. Neither a **`.send()`** on a **`SUB`** side, or a **`.recv()`** on a **`PUB`** side.

> **ZeroMQ API Specification says**:
> The **`pgm`** and **`epgm`** transports can only be used with the **`ZMQ_PUB`** and **`ZMQ_SUB`** socket types.

**`ZMQ_SUB`** archetype does not permit any **`.send()`** method.
**`ZMQ_PUB`** archetype does not permit any **`.recv()`** method.

### Q.E.D.

---

## So, how to do that, so as to create a [bi-directional signalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25729055/understanding-advanced-zeromq-socket-types/25742744#25742744)?

One has to add also another socket, most probably using a **`tcp://`** transport class, over which a feedback signalling may take place.

[image]

ZeroMQ's reverse **`.bind()`**/**`.connect()`** mechanics are a common practice for doing this in an unstructured, formally uncontrolled / configuration-policy unenforced distributed computing infrastructures.